# Android search settings for different user profiles

Tags: android, search

Does anyone know that is it possible to have a multiple user profiles in an Android device. If it is possible then will it be possible also to separate the search history or search settings for different user profiles? We are working on a custom Android device and trying to have different user profiles there. Although my job is not to find how to create multiple users but I got the task to find out how to differ the search settings for different users on the same device. I have checked almost everything in Android developer guide for searches and cant find anything like that. Any answers or clues or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple profiles on standard Android devices.  You will have to create a highly customized ROM for this.  I wish you fellows luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since you are saying that you are building a custom android device you are building the
source from Android Open Source Project(AOSP). Since you have access to the entire source code, you 
could set the system property 'fw.max_users=4' or any number you want greater than 1 to enable 
multiple user profiles on the device. You could set this value in your device's system.prop file.
This feature probably started out in Android 4.2

But I don't there is currently any way to separate search history and search settings.

I see that this question was asked a long time ago, but it may help any new users who have the same
question.